# Setting a class member value in the constructor of a KeyedProcessFunction class does not work

Tags: apache-flink

I have a class which extends `KeyedProcessFunction` in Apache Flink.

The class has a transient member, for example a `SomeType ok`

In the constructor of the said class, the class member `ok` is population to a SomeType value.

However when the `ok` is read by the `processElement` function, it complains that the `ok` is null.

`SomeType` is not serialisable and hence it is transient. Is that the reason why this is not working as expected? If so, how should I pass some state into the class which would be read by every element irrespective of the key.

Comment: I've tested and I can now confirm that the issue is because the class member is transient. It needs to be serialisable. The original question still stands, i.e. is there a way to pass non-serialisable state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All data going from JobManager's to TaskManager's needs to be serializable due to Flink distributed nature. This data is passed from JM to TM via network and that's the reason why they need to be serializable.

A way to work around this is to pass the primitive/serializeable pieces via the constructor and use the method [`RichFunction.open`](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/RichFunction.html#open-org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.OpenContext-) to initialize what is not serializable.

Comment: As you mentioned anything `transient` or `static` wont be serialized. That's the reason why they're ending empty after getting on TM runtime.

Comment: Just to clarify Pedro's answer, what he's saying is to (a) pass the (serializable) values you need to construct `SomeType` to your `KeyedProcessFunction` constructor and save them in regular (non-transient) class members, and then (b) use these values in the `open()` method to initialize the transient `SomeType` class member. The `open()` call is made after the class has been deserialized by the TaskManager, so then it's safe to create `SomeType`.

Comment: Thanks @PedroMázala I had realised that after putting up the question and subsequently added more info in the comment. Is there no other way to pass non-serialisable state to TM? Is there a doc on how to populate `open()` argument `Configuration parameters` from the JM?

Comment: I think the only way is to use the open method indeed. 

Sorry, I did not follow the second part of the question. What do you mean by populating the argument? This method should be called by Flink and already provides you with this argument. This should be called on the startup time of the TM.